# Wait until API fully loads before running next function -- async/await -- will this work?

Tags: vue.js, async-await

I am a beginner with Javascript with a bit of knowledge of VueJs. I have an array called `tickets`. I also have a data api returning two different data objects (tickets and user profiles).

The tickets have user ids and the user profiles has the ids with names.

I needed to create a method that looks at both of that data, loops through it, and assigns the full name of the user to the view.

I was having an issue where my tickets object were not finished loading and it was sometimes causing an error like `firstname is undefined`. So, i thought I'd try and write an async/await approach to wait until the tickets have fully loaded.

Although my code works, it just doesn't "feel right" and I am not sure how reliable it will be once the application gets larger.

Can I get another set of eyes as to confirmation that my current approach is OK? Thanks!

```
data() {
    return {
      isBusy: true,
      tickets: [],
      userProfiles: [],
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getUserProfiles()
    this.getTickets()
  },
  methods: {
    getUserProfiles: function() {
      ApiService.getUserProfiles().then(response => {
        this.userProfiles = response.data
      })
    },
    getTickets() {
      ApiService.getTickets().then(response => {
        this.tickets = response.data
        this.assignNames(this.tickets)
        this.isBusy = false
      })
    },

    // lets wait until the issues are loaded before showing names;
    async assignNames() {
      let tickets = await this.tickets
      var i
      for (i = 0; i < this.tickets.length; i++) {
        if (tickets[i].assigned_to !== null) {
          const result = this.userProfiles.filter(profile => {
            return profile.uid == tickets[i].assigned_to
          })
          tickets[i].assigned_to = result[0].firstname + ' ' + result[0].lastname
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could do this.  Here is the one I prefer without `async`/`await`:

```js
created() {
  this.load();
},
methods: {
  getUserProfiles: function() {
    return ApiService.getUserProfiles().then(response => {
      this.userProfiles = response.data
    })
  },
  getTickets() {
    return ApiService.getTickets().then(response => {
      this.tickets = response.data
    })
  },
  load() {
    Promise.all([
      this.getUserProfiles(),
      this.getTickets()
    ]).then(data => {
      this.assignNames();
      this.isBusy = false;
    });
  },
  assignNames(){
    const tickets = this.tickets;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tickets.length; i++) {
      if (tickets[i].assigned_to !== null) {
        const result = this.userProfiles.filter(profile => {
          return profile.uid == tickets[i].assigned_to
        })
        tickets[i].assigned_to = result[0].firstname + ' ' + result[0].lastname
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there a reason why you prefer this method over the async approach?

Comment: Welcome.  Only because I'm used to it.  `async/await` is a superior paradigm for when more complicated (nested) promises would be needed.